# Why is the word building used instead of built?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, tenses, gerunds

We use the word as **building**.  
 Generally, we use the gerund form in the present continuous tense. 
Why are we using the word *building* when it is already built?

Comment: We use the word writing similarly.  Example:  "I cannot read your writing"

Comment: _i love the painting_.  is a similar example

Answer (score 4):

*Building (n.)* is a [verbal noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun) derived from the verb *build* by adding the *-ing* suffix. A building does not necessarily connote a finished structure, it can be an unfinished structure as well.

Here are all the senses listed in *[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/building)*:

> `1` a relatively permanent enclosed construction over a plot of land, having a roof and usually windows and often more than one level, used for any of a wide variety of activities, as living, entertaining, or manufacturing. 
> `2` anything built or constructed. 
> `3` the act, business, or practice of constructing houses, office buildings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples of what you're looking for - the built environment; the written word. In these cases, the completed form of the verb is used as an adjective.

In the declaration, 'It is written!' Or 'Let it be written!' there is also a clear sense of completion intended.

In the example you gave, 'building' is a noun, commonly referred to as a 'gerund', or 'verbal', a word derived from a verb, often used as a noun. The forms refer to 'the act of doing something' rather than the process of doing it as an activity through time. In this sense, a building (structure) is the product of an act of building (activity). As such, it stands for the act which produced it, and becomes a rather beautiful metaphorical use of linguistic thought.